Get aggregates for a dataframe with different combinations
Total pyspark noob here. I have a dataframe similar to this:
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(ttype='C', amt='12.99', dt='2024/01/01'),
  Row(ttype='D', amt='21.99', dt='2024/02/15'),
  Row(ttype='C', amt='16.99', dt='2024/01/21'),
])

I want to find the average amt for the last 30, 60 and 90 days for ttype='C' and ttype='D'
I can do this one at a time:
#pseudo code
df.filter('ttype=C for the last 30 days`).avg()
df.filter('ttype=D for the last 30 days`).avg()
df.filter('ttype=C for the last 60 days`).avg()
df.filter('ttype=D for the last 90 days`).avg()
...

but I am looking for a more elegant way to do this.

do you mean the last 30 days in real time, or the last 30 records that exist for each ttype ?

30/60/90 days in real time.

@mithun_dea thanks for following up. in that case, i'll need to revise my solution a bit

One possibility would be to create a column that keeps track of the number of days before the current date for each record then perform a groupby over ttype to get averages. For example:
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, FloatType, StringType

start_day = pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('90D')

## create sample spark DataFrame
pandasDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'ttype': ['C']*90 + ['D']*90,
    'amt': [1]*30 + [2]*30 + [3]*30 + [4]*30 + [5]*30 + [6]*30,
    'dt': pd.date_range(start=start_day.date(), periods=90).append(
        pd.date_range(start=start_day.date(), periods=90)
    )
})

sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn("days_before_today", F.date_diff(F.current_date(), F.col('dt')))

## create a spark DataFrame to hold the results
resultsDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(),
    schema=StructType([
        StructField('ttype', StringType(), True),
        StructField('amt', FloatType(), True),
        StructField('number_of_records', IntegerType(), True)
    ])
)

for number_of_records in [30,60,90]:
    resultsDF = resultsDF.union(
        sparkDF.filter(
            F.col('days_before_today') <= number_of_records
        ).groupby(
            F.col('ttype')
        ).agg(
            F.avg('amt').alias('avg_amt')
        ).withColumn(
            'number_of_records', F.lit(number_of_records)
        )
    )

Result:
+-----+---+-----------------+
|ttype|amt|number_of_records|
+-----+---+-----------------+
|    C|3.0|               30|
|    D|6.0|               30|
|    C|2.5|               60|
|    D|5.5|               60|
|    C|2.0|               90|
|    D|5.0|               90|
+-----+---+-----------------+

